# If Irene is "valid", why does she have a risk of heart attack?

Tags: gattaca

Irene is "valid", and "valid" people are supposed to have perfectly healthy bodies. If she was conceived the same way Vincent's brother Anton and all "valid" people are, why does her body still have a "fault"?

And since she cannot go to space, what occupation does she have at Gattaca? Despite saying she isn't allowed to go to space, she looks like one of the astronauts and e.g. attends the concerto with the other astronauts. Gattaca's director said their requirements became stricter, but since Irene was still employed there, she obviously still had an occupation there.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [original script](https://sfy.ru/?script=gattaca), her heart condition isn't something that's likely to be an issue until she's into her retirement, and well past breeding age. Given her superior looks and IQ, this is apparently sufficient to make her a 'valid', even if she's flawed.

> **IRENE:** (enjoying his unease) *It's here.  My heart.* (adding quickly)
> *I'm careful--weekly check-ups.  I'm on a drug maintenance program,
> blood thinners, diet--*(slowly removing his hand) *I just want you to
> know what you'd be getting yourself into.*
>
> **JEROME:** *What exactly is wrong?*
>
> **IRENE:** *Nothing yet.  I'll start experiencing symptoms in my
> late-fifties.* (matter-of-fact) *But unless they come up with something
> between now and then, I won't live much past 67.*

As to her job, she's the Director's Assistant, again, at least in the original script.

> DIRECTOR JOSEF, 50's, a shorter, official-looking man approaches.  His
> assistant IRENE stands at his shoulder.

Whereas in the film she appears to be a 'Celestial Navigator' like Jerome. It's not clear if she's the same class as him (e.g. 1st Class) or what the class system refers to.